# Triple list VS double dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, document, bigdata

I have 40.000 documents, 93.08 words per doc. on avg., where every word is a number (which can index a dictionary) and every word has a count (frequency). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943793/how-to-store-this-collection-of-documents).

I am between two data structures to store the data and was wondering which one I should choose, which one the Python people would choose!

**Triple-list:**

A list, where every node:

__ is  a list, where every node:

__.... is a list of two values; `word_id` and `count`.

**Double-dictionary:**

A dictionary, with keys the `doc_id` and values dictionaries.

That value dictionary would have a `word_id` as a key and the `count` as a value.

---

I feel that the first will require less space (since it doesn't store the `doc_id`), while the second will be more easy to handle and access. I mean, accessing the i-element in the list is O(n), while it is constant in the dictionary, *I think*. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Accessing the ith element of a list is O(1).

Comment: @AlexHall really? Can you point me to some "evidence" about it? In [tag:C] it's O(n).

Comment: @gsamaras Accessing the ith element in a list in nearly every programming language, C included, is O(1).

Think about it this way: an array is stored as a contiguous block of memory.  I'm not too sure how the internal Python implementation works (because Python lists are inherently generic), but the argument still holds - if you have an array of size N, then the i-th element is located at `(address for beginning of array in memory) + (i * size of element)`.

Comment: A simple linked list is O(n) @RushyPanchal.

Comment: Accessing an index is indeed O(1) but FINDING an element in a list with an unknown index is O(n)

Comment: Python lists are not linked lists, they are like Java ArrayLists or C++ vectors. They're dynamically growing arrays which you can randomly access by calculating an offset. But yes, in many languages the word list by default means linked list.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was meaning what @MateHegedus said! Alex Hall, that clears things up! ;)

Comment: @gsamaras A list is vastly different from a linked list. Searching a list, of course, is naturally O(n) unless you know something about the contents and ordering.

Comment: Here's a good reference for time complexity of Python lists: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Chris that's what I was searching for, thank you!

Comment: Also, accessing the ith element of a C array is O(1) because `a[i]` is functionally equivalent to `*(a + i)`, where `a` is a pointer to the start of an array (which is how arrays are represented) and `a + i` is just pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a dictionary. It will make handling your code easier to understand and to program and it will have a lower complexity as well.

The only reason you would use a list, is if you cared about the order of the documents.

Comment: But it would require more space, right? I do not care about the order. ;)

Comment: @gsamaras As a factor of N, it would not.

Comment: @gsamaras The only additional space is for the keys, but Python strings are only stored "once" in memory per string – that is, if you have the same set of keys for each element, then it's a constant additional space (which is negligible).

Comment: @RushyPanchal which strings? `doc_id`, `word_id` and `count` are numbers, integers to be exact. Mate, in big o notation of course, but in practice?

Comment: @gsamaras the keys for a dictionary, unless you are storing them as something else. But if you're using a dictionary for clarity, then it seems intuitive to also use strings for keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order of the items you should definitely use a dictionary because dictionaries are used to group associated data while lists are generally used to group more generic items.

Moreover lookups in dictionaries are faster than that of a list.

Lookups in lists are O(n) while lookups in dictionaries are O(1). though lists are considerably larger in Memory than lists

Comment: Yes I do not care about the order!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you just want to store a large amount of numbers, for which the most space efficient choice is an [array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html). These are one-dimensional so you could write a class which takes in three indices (the last being 0 for `word_id` and 1 for `count`) and does some basic addition and multiplication to find the correct 1D index.

Comment: Why this got a downvote? I will upvote, since the idea doesn't seem bad and the downvoter didn't justify his/her action.