# Why GIL is not synchrionizing Python threads that are running native C++ code inside a DLL?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, python-multithreading

I have developed a simple multi-threaded Python application (Python 3.7) to call 8 different compute-intensive tasks within 8 threads . The tasks can be either a Python code or a C++ code that is embedded inside a DLL and is accessible through ctypes package. I am running the experiments on a 8-core machine on Windows.

The strange point is that when all the threads call the Python code, it seems that only one thread is active at an specific time and the CPU utilization is around 12.5%. But when calling the C++ code inside the DLL, the whole cores are used and the CPU utilization is 100%.

Now, the question is that why GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) is not synchronizing Python threads that call native C++ codes? Is the ctypes implementation releases the GIL when calling the native C++ code?

**Edit 1:** No macro like [Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS) is used inside the Native C++ DLL.

Comment: If you're using ctypes, maybe ctypes calls that macro.

Comment: ctypes has several references to 'releasing the GIL' https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [[Python 3]: ctypes - Loading shared libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries) (**emphasis** is mine; thanks @user2357112 for pointing out this very explicit quote (waay better than what I've originally posted)):

> **The Python [global interpreter lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) is released before calling any function exported by these libraries, and reacquired afterwards**.

You can also find this statement in other forms on the same page (check *PyDLL*, *CFUNCTYPE*).

There are ways of going around the *GIL* limitation:

- Replacing the *threading* module usage by *multiprocessing* ([[Python 3]: multiprocessing - Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#module-multiprocessing)). This is the most common one
- Enclosing code blocks that can be executed in parallel in *Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS* / *Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS*. The drawback would be that the *.dll*(s) will now depend on *Python*

Comment: There's a more explicit statement below the docs for CDLL, OleDLL, and WinDLL: "The Python global interpreter lock is released before calling any function exported by these libraries, and reacquired afterwards."

Comment: @user2357112: Thank you for this fragment! I updated the answer.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. Do you khnow if it is the same case for all other packages for loading DLLs in Python, such as Boost.Python?

Comment: Not a *Boost* user, but If what I know is correct, *Boost* is used to create extension modules (written in *C*), kind of like *Swig* does. Being *Python* modules, they fall under *GIL* umbrella.

Comment: @CristiFati Ahaa, and what about .pyd modules that compiled from a .cpp files? Do they fall under the GIL umbrella as well?

Comment: Of course. It's executed by the interpreter, no matter the programming language it's written in.

Comment: @CristiFati Well, in the case of .pyd files, who should release the GIL? The code inside the .pyd file or the client that uses the .pyd file? BTW, I know that in C there are some macros (e.g. Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS) for releaseing the GIL, but is there such a Macro in Python to release the GIL?

Comment: *Python* code is **always** meant to run under *GIL*, one of the design features (and nowadays weaknesses), so it can't be disabled. Pure *C* code on the other hand shouldn't "benefit" from *GIL* restriction, therefore the existence of the macros. No one ***should*** release the *GIL*. Is just a feature for bypassing it when needed (in case of parallel operations).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185548/discussion-between-cristifati-and-hsalimi).